# Enclosure for old IDE hard drives

Tags: hard-disk

I have two internal HDD - one laptop and one desktop. The interface is ATA-100/IDE

Laptop - Fujitsu MHV2040AH
https://www.cnet.com/products/fujitsu-mobile-mhv2040ah-hard-drive-40-gb-ata-100-series/

Desktop - Maxtor 6Y080L0
https://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=en&model=MAXTOR%206Y080L0

I'm looking for an enclosure for the above two. What sort of enclosure will work for this?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to connect them for data extraction? https://www.amazon.com/Hard-Drive-Enclosures-IDE-SATA-Accessories/s?rh=n%3A160354011%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_browse-bin%3A5871549011

Comment: Apologies for the late comeback. I actually have Linux OS running off those hard drives. They aren't that high capacity (40GB and 80GB) to use for data storage.

Comment: I think it may be time to replace those drives, at least as boot volumes...